# Integration of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus

I am having some difficulties with the calculation of the following integral. Can somebody help me please?

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+a\cos x},\text{ for }0<a<1$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: It is not the same question. It is another exercise..

Comment: It's the same basic integral rewritten.  You've now had 3 people give you the same answer on 3 separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

**Detailed hint:**

Wikipedia calls this the [The Weierstrass Substitutiion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula#The_Weierstrass_substitution): when $t=\tan(\theta/2)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta)&=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\\
\cos(\theta)&=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\\
\tan(\theta)&=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\\
\mathrm{d}\theta&=\frac{2\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**: $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ which $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$.

**Hint 2**: $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}\Rightarrow dt=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx=\frac{1}{2}(t^2+1)dx$.

Comment: How do you replace the dx in integral expression ? I have a similar integral to calculate

Comment: So we have: $\int \frac{\frac{2}{t^2+1}}{1+a\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute, $t = \tan \left(\dfrac x2\right)$. So $x = 2\tan^{-1}t$ and $dx = \dfrac{2dt}{1+t^2}$. And the integral becomes,

$$\begin{align*}\int\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{1+t^2}}{1+\dfrac{a(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}}dt
&=\dfrac2{(1+a)}\int\dfrac1{1+\left[t\dfrac{\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\right]^2}dt
&\color{blue}{u =\left[t\frac{\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\right]\Rightarrow dt = \frac{\sqrt{1+a}}{\sqrt{1-a}}du }\\
&=\dfrac2{(1+a)}\frac{\sqrt{1+a}}{\sqrt{1-a}}\int\dfrac1{1+u^2}du
&\color{blue}{\int\dfrac1{1+u^2}du= \tan^{-1}u}\\
\\&=\dfrac2{(1+a)}\frac{\sqrt{1+a}}{\sqrt{1-a}}\tan^{-1}u\\\\
&=\dfrac2{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\tan^{-1}u&\color{blue}{u =\left[t\frac{\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\right]}\\ \\
&=\dfrac{2\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\cdot\tan \left(\dfrac x2\right)\right]}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

$$\displaystyle\Large\therefore \boxed{\int \dfrac1{1+acosx}dx =\dfrac{2\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\cdot\tan \left(\dfrac x2\right)\right]}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} }$$